# Why is "exit with 0" not printed when stopping the VS Code debugger?

Tags: go, signals, vscode-debugger

When running the following Go with the VS Code debugger, why does it not print `exit with 0` when stopping the debugger?

1. at first notice signal and run a simple goroutine for printing a message to mean that the process is running
2. at second `<- signal` means stop the process when notice the signal, but the debugger in VS Code does not print `exit with 0`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // notice signal
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sig, os.Kill, os.Interrupt)

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            fmt.Println("tick")
        }
    }()
    // stop the process when notice signal
    <-sig
    fmt.Println("exit with 0")
}
```

Comment: It seems the support is still not there in vscode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2658

Comment: It take time to run fmt.Println. By that time the program exit.
Sleep for 100 mills and you should see the log.

Comment: thx, got it. awesome answer.